# Set Scroll To Top on Tab bar layout in Android studio

Tags: android

I have a tab layout on one of my App, how can I set it in such a way that when an icon is clicked, it will scroll to the top, I want to achieve this because i have a very long recycleView on my app

This is a code for example that shows an icon on my app frontend.

```
  // Feed tab

        mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout);
        tab_icon = (ImageView) mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.tab_icon);
        tab_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_feed_n);
        tab_badge = (TextView) mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.tab_badge2);
        tab_badge.setText("Home");
        tab_layout = (LinearLayout) mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.tab_main_layout);
        tab_layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                   
                    animateTab(0);
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

What code should I use on this to make it scroll to top on click, I tried this " scrollView.setScrollY(0);" but it shows an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'scrollView'"

Comment: linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos, 0);

Comment: recyclerview.scrollToPosition(position)

Comment: The above two suggestions not working, thanks for the answer